# Generating all distinct permutations of a list in R

Tags: r, permutation

I'm trying to create a list of permutations of a list, such that, for example, `perms(list("a", "b", "c"))` returns

```
list(list("a", "b", "c"), list("a", "c", "b"), list("b", "a", "c"),
     list("b", "c", "a"), list("c", "a", "b"), list("c", "b", "a"))
```

I'm not sure how to proceed, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are several packages for generating permutations in R. I wrote a **[summary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47983855/4408538)** that includes  benchmarks as well as demonstrations of usage for each available method.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`combinat::permn` will do that work:

```
> library(combinat)
> permn(letters[1:3])
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"

[[2]]
[1] "a" "c" "b"

[[3]]
[1] "c" "a" "b"

[[4]]
[1] "c" "b" "a"

[[5]]
[1] "b" "c" "a"

[[6]]
[1] "b" "a" "c"
```

Note that calculation is huge if the element is large.

Comment: How about the case when from 3 letter string we would like to have not only all 3 letter elements but also 2 letter and 1 letter elements?

Comment: What is the maximum number of elements in the vector that the function can accept?

Answer (score 65):

A while back I had to do this in base R without loading any packages.

```
permutations <- function(n){
    if(n==1){
        return(matrix(1))
    } else {
        sp <- permutations(n-1)
        p <- nrow(sp)
        A <- matrix(nrow=n*p,ncol=n)
        for(i in 1:n){
            A[(i-1)*p+1:p,] <- cbind(i,sp+(sp>=i))
        }
        return(A)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
> matrix(letters[permutations(3)],ncol=3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "a"  "b"  "c" 
[2,] "a"  "c"  "b" 
[3,] "b"  "a"  "c" 
[4,] "b"  "c"  "a" 
[5,] "c"  "a"  "b" 
[6,] "c"  "b"  "a"
```

Comment: Nice function. Seems pretty fast too.

Comment: This function is much faster than combinat::permn with a larger number of permutations.  For example:
microbenchmark:microbenchmark(permn(letters[1:9]), 
               matrix(letters[permutations(9)],ncol=9),
               times=20)

Answer (score 38):

base R can also provide the answer:

```
all <- expand.grid(p1 = letters[1:3], p2 = letters[1:3], p3 = letters[1:3], stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
perms <- all[apply(all, 1, function(x) {length(unique(x)) == 3}),]
```

Answer (score 37):

You can try `permutations()` from the `gtools` package, but unlike `permn()` from `combinat`, it doesn't output a list:

```
> library(gtools)
> permutations(3, 3, letters[1:3])
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "a"  "b"  "c" 
[2,] "a"  "c"  "b" 
[3,] "b"  "a"  "c" 
[4,] "b"  "c"  "a" 
[5,] "c"  "a"  "b" 
[6,] "c"  "b"  "a"
```

Comment: It deserves noting that `permutations` is more flexible. It allows permutating m of n elements and allow repeated use of elements. I found this after trying `permn` without success.

Comment: It cannot generate all the possible permutations when the `v` Source Vector has repeated elements. So let's say that I want to get all the possible permutations of the word `letters`

Answer (score 20):

A solution in base R, no dependencies on other packages:

```
> getPermutations <- function(x) {
    if (length(x) == 1) {
        return(x)
    }
    else {
        res <- matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = length(x))
        for (i in seq_along(x)) {
            res <- rbind(res, cbind(x[i], Recall(x[-i])))
        }
        return(res)
    }
}

> getPermutations(letters[1:3])
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "a"  "b"  "c" 
[2,] "a"  "c"  "b" 
[3,] "b"  "a"  "c" 
[4,] "b"  "c"  "a" 
[5,] "c"  "a"  "b" 
[6,] "c"  "b"  "a"
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Outperforms the `gtools` solution.

Comment: Haven't tested before, but it seems so. Cool.

Answer (score 12):

Try:

```
> a = letters[1:3]
> eg = expand.grid(a,a,a)
> eg[!(eg$Var1==eg$Var2 | eg$Var2==eg$Var3 | eg$Var1==eg$Var3),]
   Var1 Var2 Var3
6     c    b    a
8     b    c    a
12    c    a    b
16    a    c    b
20    b    a    c
22    a    b    c
```

As suggested by @Adrian in comments, last line can be replaced by:

```
eg[apply(eg, 1, anyDuplicated) == 0, ]
```

Comment: or, for the last line: `eg[apply(eg, 1, anyDuplicated) == 0, ]`

Comment: @dusadrian A note on scalability: I would think twice before using this approach in "serious" code, as the searched space (eg), grows unreasonably huge as the sample size/sampled set increases (hit rate: n! vs. n^n - worsens near-exponentially estimated from Stirling's formula).

For the 10 out of 10 case, the hit ratio is only `prod(1:10) / (10 ^ 10) = 0.036%` already. And it seems all those examined variants are at some point stored in memory, in a data frame. However, I always liked this one for small manual tasks as it's so easy to understand.

Comment: @brezniczky Yes indeed, this is only for demonstrative purposes. I have a completely different solution (down this thread), which is self contained. Both use plain R, but of course for more intensive memory operations one should implement some compiled code (most of the R's internal functions are written in C, actually).

Answer (score 11):

```
# Another recursive implementation    
# for those who like to roll their own, no package required 
    permutations <- function( x, prefix = c() )
    {
        if(length(x) == 0 ) return(prefix)
        do.call(rbind, sapply(1:length(x), FUN = function(idx) permutations( x[-idx], c( prefix, x[idx])), simplify = FALSE))
    }

    permutations(letters[1:3])
    #    [,1] [,2] [,3]
    #[1,] "a"  "b"  "c" 
    #[2,] "a"  "c"  "b" 
    #[3,] "b"  "a"  "c" 
    #[4,] "b"  "c"  "a" 
    #[5,] "c"  "a"  "b" 
    #[6,] "c"  "b"  "a"
```

Comment: Great answer! What about dropping the `sapply(...,  simplify = FALSE)` and use `lapply(...)` instead?

Answer (score 5):

A fun solution "probabilistic" using sample for base R:

```
elements <- c("a", "b", "c")
k <- length(elements)
res=unique(t(sapply(1:200, function(x) sample(elements, k))))
# below, check you have all the permutations you need (if not, try again)
nrow(res) == factorial(k)
res
```

basically you call many random samples, hoping to get them all, and you unique them.

Answer (score 3):

Behold, the `purrr`  solution:

```
> map(1:3, ~ c('a', 'b', 'c')) %>%
    cross() %>%
    keep(~ length(unique(.x)) == 3) %>%
    map(unlist)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "c" "b" "a"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "b" "c" "a"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "c" "a" "b"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "a" "c" "b"
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] "b" "a" "c"
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Answer (score 2):

## We can use base function `combn` with a little modifcation:

```
   combn_n <- function(x) {
      m <- length(x) - 1 # number of elements to choose: n-1 
      xr <- rev(x) # reversed x
      part_1 <- rbind(combn(x, m), xr, deparse.level = 0) 
      part_2 <- rbind(combn(xr, m), x, deparse.level = 0) 
      cbind(part_1, part_2)
       }
```

```
  combn_n(letters[1:3])

[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]  
[1,] "a"  "a"  "b"  "c"  "c"  "b"   
[2,] "b"  "c"  "c"  "b"  "a"  "a"   
[3,] "c"  "b"  "a"  "a"  "b"  "c"
```

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps, there is the "arrangements" package, that allows you to simply do :

```
> abc  = letters[1:3]

> permutations(abc)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "a"  "b"  "c" 
[2,] "a"  "c"  "b" 
[3,] "b"  "a"  "c" 
[4,] "b"  "c"  "a" 
[5,] "c"  "a"  "b" 
[6,] "c"  "b"  "a"
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic version of [rnso's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25904154/5861244) is:

```r
get_perms <- function(x){
  stopifnot(is.atomic(x)) # for the matrix call to make sense
  out <- as.matrix(expand.grid(
    replicate(length(x), x, simplify = FALSE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
  out[apply(out,1, anyDuplicated) == 0, ]
}
```

Here are two examples:

```r
get_perms(letters[1:3])
#R>      Var1 Var2 Var3
#R> [1,] "c"  "b"  "a" 
#R> [2,] "b"  "c"  "a" 
#R> [3,] "c"  "a"  "b" 
#R> [4,] "a"  "c"  "b" 
#R> [5,] "b"  "a"  "c" 
#R> [6,] "a"  "b"  "c" 
get_perms(letters[1:4])
#R>       Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
#R>  [1,] "d"  "c"  "b"  "a" 
#R>  [2,] "c"  "d"  "b"  "a" 
#R>  [3,] "d"  "b"  "c"  "a" 
#R>  [4,] "b"  "d"  "c"  "a" 
#R>  [5,] "c"  "b"  "d"  "a" 
#R>  [6,] "b"  "c"  "d"  "a" 
#R>  [7,] "d"  "c"  "a"  "b" 
#R>  [8,] "c"  "d"  "a"  "b" 
#R>  [9,] "d"  "a"  "c"  "b" 
#R> [10,] "a"  "d"  "c"  "b" 
#R> [11,] "c"  "a"  "d"  "b" 
#R> [12,] "a"  "c"  "d"  "b" 
#R> [13,] "d"  "b"  "a"  "c" 
#R> [14,] "b"  "d"  "a"  "c" 
#R> [15,] "d"  "a"  "b"  "c" 
#R> [16,] "a"  "d"  "b"  "c" 
#R> [17,] "b"  "a"  "d"  "c" 
#R> [18,] "a"  "b"  "d"  "c" 
#R> [19,] "c"  "b"  "a"  "d" 
#R> [20,] "b"  "c"  "a"  "d" 
#R> [21,] "c"  "a"  "b"  "d" 
#R> [22,] "a"  "c"  "b"  "d" 
#R> [23,] "b"  "a"  "c"  "d" 
#R> [24,] "a"  "b"  "c"  "d"
```

One can also slightly alter [Rick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29023189/5861244) by using `lapply`, only doing a single `rbind`, and reduce the number of `[s]/[l]apply` calls:

```r
permutations <- function(x, prefix = c()){
  if(length(x) == 1) # was zero before
    return(list(c(prefix, x)))
  out <- do.call(c, lapply(1:length(x), function(idx) 
    permutations(x[-idx], c(prefix, x[idx]))))
  if(length(prefix) > 0L)
    return(out)
  
  do.call(rbind, out)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What about

```
pmsa <- function(l) {
  pms <- function(n) if(n==1) return(list(1)) else unlist(lapply(pms(n-1),function(v) lapply(0:(n-1),function(k) append(v,n,k))),recursive = F)
  lapply(pms(length(l)),function(.) l[.])
}
```

This gives a list. Then

`pmsa(letters[1:3])`