# List all 3 digit combinations out of 6 digits

Tags: r, combinations, combinatorics

Let's say I have 6 numbers:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

I want to list all possible 3 digit combinations of these 6 numbers, including repetitions.

The desired result would look like this:

```
1 1 1
1 2 3
1 2 4
...
```

I do not want to include elements that have the same 3 numbers but in a different order:

for example

```
1 2 3
3 2 1
```

should exclude one of them

Comment: `expand.grid(1:6, 1:6, 1:6)`

Comment: This looks similar to a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095992/generating-all-distinct-permutations-of-a-list-in-r).

Comment: sorry I left out one detail. please see my update

Comment: For the edit, just subset: `df <- expand.grid(1:6, 1:6, 1:6); df[df$Var1 <= df$Var2 & df$Var2 <= df$Var3,]`

Comment: this doesn't seem to work. it outputs the same number of rows

Comment: I get 56 rows from @alistaire 's code.

Comment: You can also do `library(gtools); combinations(n=6, r=3, v=a, repeats.allowed=TRUE)`.

Comment: yes both methods work. THanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expand.grid` returns a data.frame of combinations, picking one from each set you supply it. If you `1 2 3` is not the same as `3 2 1`, subset it to get just the rows you want.

```
df <- expand.grid(1:6, 1:6, 1:6)
df[df$Var1 <= df$Var2 & df$Var2 <= df$Var3,]
# 
#     Var1 Var2 Var3
# 1      1    1    1
# 37     1    1    2
# 43     1    2    2
# 44     2    2    2
# 73     1    1    3
# 79     1    2    3
# 80     2    2    3
# 85     1    3    3
# 86     2    3    3
# 87     3    3    3
# 109    1    1    4
# 115    1    2    4
# 116    2    2    4
# 121    1    3    4
# 122    2    3    4
# 123    3    3    4
# 127    1    4    4
# 128    2    4    4
# 129    3    4    4
# 130    4    4    4
# 145    1    1    5
# 151    1    2    5
# 152    2    2    5
# 157    1    3    5
# 158    2    3    5
# 159    3    3    5
# 163    1    4    5
# 164    2    4    5
# 165    3    4    5
# 166    4    4    5
# 169    1    5    5
# 170    2    5    5
# 171    3    5    5
# 172    4    5    5
# 173    5    5    5
# 181    1    1    6
# 187    1    2    6
# 188    2    2    6
# 193    1    3    6
# 194    2    3    6
# 195    3    3    6
# 199    1    4    6
# 200    2    4    6
# 201    3    4    6
# 202    4    4    6
# 205    1    5    6
# 206    2    5    6
# 207    3    5    6
# 208    4    5    6
# 209    5    5    6
# 211    1    6    6
# 212    2    6    6
# 213    3    6    6
# 214    4    6    6
# 215    5    6    6
# 216    6    6    6
```

Answer (score 5):

The `combinations` function from `gtools` can do this:

```
library(gtools)
combinations(n=6, r=3, v=a, repeats.allowed=TRUE)
```

> ```
>       [,1] [,2] [,3]
>  [1,]    1    1    1
>  [2,]    1    1    2
>  [3,]    1    1    3
>  ...
> [54,]    5    5    6
> [55,]    5    6    6
> [56,]    6    6    6
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Below, is a general function that allows you to specify constraints on the output. For example, I have had many situations to arise whereby I needed all n-tuples of a given set such that there product was less than a given bound. Before I wrote this function, I was forced to use `combinations` and search for those rows that met my condition. This took a lot of time and a lot of memory.

```
Combo  <- function(n,r,v=1:n,li=10^8,fun1="prod",fun2="<",repeats.allowed=FALSE) {
    ## where fun1 is a general function such as "prod", "sum", "sd", etc.
    ## and fun2 is a comparison operator such as "<", "<=", ">", "==",  etc.

    myfun <- match.fun(FUN = fun1)
    operator1 <- match.fun(FUN = fun2)
    operator2 <- match.fun(FUN = fun2)
    myv <- sort(v)

    if (fun2 %in% c(">",">=")) {
        myv <- rev(myv)
        TheLim <- min(v)
    } else {
        TheLim <- max(v)
        if (fun2 == "==") {
            operator1 <- match.fun(FUN = "<=")
        }
    }

    if (!repeats.allowed) {
        m <- matrix(numeric(0),combinat::nCm(n,r),r)
        v1 <- myv; n1 <- length(v); t <- TRUE; count <- 0L

        while (t) {
            t <- operator1(myfun(v1[1:r]),li)
            while (t && length(v1)>=r) {
                t_1 <- operator2(myfun(v1[1:r]),li)
                if (t_1) {count <- count+1L; m[count,] <- v1[1:r]}
                v1 <- v1[-r]
                t <- operator1(myfun(v1[1:r],na.rm=TRUE),li)
            }
            if (t) {
                s <- 1:length(v1)
                mymax <- myv[n1-(r-s)]
                t1 <- which(!v1==mymax)
                if (length(t1)>0) {
                    e <- max(t1)
                    v1[e] <- myv[which(myv==v1[e])+1L]
                    v1 <- c(v1[1:e],myv[(which(myv==v1[e])+1L):n1])
                } else {
                    return(m[!is.na(m[,1]),])
                }
            } else {
                r1 <- r-1L
                while (r1>=1L && !t) {
                    v1[r1] <- myv[which(myv==v1[r1])+1L]
                    if (v1[r1]==TheLim) {r1 <- r1-1L; next}
                    v1 <- c(v1[1:r1],myv[(which(myv==v1[r1])+1L):n1])
                    t <- operator1(myfun(v1[1:r],na.rm=TRUE),li) && length(v1)>=r
                    r1 <- r1-1L
                }
                if (!t) {return(m[!is.na(m[,1]),])}
            }
        }
    } else {
        MySet <- 1:n 
        for (i in 1:(r-1L)) {MySet <- sapply(1:n, function(x) sum(MySet[1:x]))}
        m <- matrix(numeric(0),nrow=MySet[n],ncol=r)
        v1 <- c(rep(myv[1], r),myv[2:n]); n1 <- length(v); t <- TRUE; count <- 0L

        while (t) {
            t <- operator1(myfun(v1[1:r]),li)
            while (t && length(v1)>=r) {
                t_1 <- operator2(myfun(v1[1:r]),li)
                if (t_1) {count <- count+1L; m[count,] <- v1[1:r]}
                v1 <- v1[-r]
                t <- operator1(myfun(v1[1:r],na.rm=TRUE),li)
            }
            if (t) {
                s <- 1:length(v1)
                t1 <- which(!v1==TheLim)
                if (length(t1)>0) {
                    e <- max(t1)
                    v1[e] <- myv[which(myv==v1[e])+1L]
                    tSize <- r - length(myv[1:e])
                    if (!v1[e]==TheLim) {
                        v1 <- c(v1[1:e],rep(v1[e],tSize),myv[(which(myv==v1[e])+1L):n1])
                    } else {
                        v1 <- c(v1[1:e],rep(v1[e],tSize))
                    }
                } else {
                    return(m[!is.na(m[,1]),])
                }
            } else {
                r1 <- r-1L
                while (r1>=1L && !t) {
                    if (v1[r1]==TheLim) {r1 <- r1-1L; next}
                    v1[r1] <- myv[which(myv==v1[r1])+1L]
                    tSize <- r - length(myv[1:r1])
                    v1 <- c(v1[1:r1],rep(v1[r1],tSize),myv[(which(myv==v1[r1])+1L):n1])
                    t <- operator1(myfun(v1[1:r],na.rm=TRUE),li) && length(v1)>=r
                    r1 <- r1-1L
                }
                if (!t) {return(m[!is.na(m[,1]),])}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below are some examples:

```
## return all 3-tuple combinations of 1 through 6 such 
## that the PRODUCT is less than 10
> Combo(n=6, r=3, v=1:6, li=10, fun1="prod", fun2="<", repeats.allowed=TRUE)
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    1    1
 [2,]    1    1    2
         .    .    .
[10,]    1    3    3
[11,]    2    2    2

## return all 3-tuple combinations of 1 through 6 such 
## that the SUM is less than 10
> Combo(n=6, r=3, v=1:6, li=10, fun1="sum", fun2="<", repeats.allowed=TRUE)
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    1    1
 [2,]    1    1    2
 [3,]    1    1    3
         .    .    .
[20,]    2    3    3
[21,]    2    3    4
[22,]    3    3    3
```

Here are some cool example involving prime numbers:

```
> library(numbers)
> myps <- Primes(1000)
> system.time(t1 <- Combo(n=length(myps), r=3, v=myps, li=10^5, fun1="prod",  fun2="<", repeats.allowed=TRUE))
user  system elapsed 
0.18    0.00    0.18 
> nrow(t1)
[1] 13465

> set.seed(42)
> t1[sample(nrow(t1),5),]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   13   31  197
[2,]   17   19  167
[3,]    2  131  227
[4,]   11   11  751
[5,]    5   31  151

> object.size(t1)
323360 bytes

> system.time(t2 <- combinations(n=length(myps), r=3, v=myps, repeats.allowed=TRUE))
user  system elapsed 
3.63    0.00    3.68
> nrow(t2)
[1] 804440

> system.time(t3 <- t2[which(sapply(1:nrow(t2), function(x) prod(t2[x,]) < 10^5)),])
user  system elapsed 
1.55    0.00    1.54 

> nrow(t3)
[1] 13465

> object.size(t2)
19306760 bytes
```

As you can see, the `Combo` function is much faster and performed in one step, whereas the `combinations/sapply` duo is slow (more than 5 seconds) and two clunky steps.  The `Combo` function also returns an object that is almost 60 times smaller.

Here is another cool example. Let's say you want to find all 3-tuples of the first 168 primes (i.e. primes < 1000) such that the standard deviation is less than 50. No problem (with the same setup as above):

```
> system.time(t1 <- Combo(n=length(myps), r=3, v=myps, li=50, fun1="sd",  fun2="<", repeats.allowed=TRUE))
user  system elapsed 
1.49    0.00    1.48

> system.time(t3 <- t2[which(sapply(1:nrow(t2), function(x) sd(t2[x,]) < 50)),])
user  system elapsed 
19.89    0.00   19.89 

> nrow(t1)
[1] 22906

> nrow(t3)
[1] 22906

> all(t3==t1)
[1] TRUE
```

It should be noted that all function combinations don't work.  For example if you let `fun1="sd"` and `fun2=">"`, the above code will return 0 matches. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this is using three for loop. Does this result what you want?

```
for (x in 1:6) { 
    for (y in x:6) {
        for (z in y:6) {
            print(paste(x,y,z))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It'd be more useful to return integers than strings, and better yet to store them.

Comment: How is printing numbers to console is useful in anyway?

Comment: You can change the print function to other function to meet your aim rather than just print the strings to console.