# Print all permutations of a vector of characters in R

Tags: r, algorithm, permutation

For starters, forgive my math terminology ignorance (I'll edit this question, once errors in my vocabulary are pointed out).

How can I print a complete set of 3 element permutation of a 10 element vector in R?

Let's assume a vector consists of 10 unique letters A to J

```
x<- LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 10 )]
```

I'd like to list (print) all possible *3 unique element* permutations, for example:

ABC, ACB, ABD, ADB ... *etc*

Thank you for any hints

Comment: You might want to check out [Generating all distinct permutations of a list in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095992/generating-all-distinct-permutations-of-a-list-in-r), which might be all you need.

Comment: Or you have a look on package `gtools` with function `permutations(n = 10, r = 3, v = x, repeats.allowed = FALSE)`

Comment: Looks like permn(x) will print all permutation for the whole vector. I can't figure out how to limit it to a 3 element option.

Comment: Thanks @wolf_wue. That's what I was looking for. If you want, I'll accept it as an answer to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be easily done using the gtools package.

```
prm <- gtools::permutations(n=10, r=3, v=LETTERS[1:10])
```

Then you can apply paste0 across the rows to get a vector.

```
apply(prm, 1, function(x)paste0(x, collapse=''))
```

Answer (score 0):

similar to [collin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6125254/collin) using new pipe you can write as:

```
LETTERS[1:10] |> permutations(n=10,r=3) |> apply(1,paste, collapse = '')
```