# compute all permutation with repetition of list R

Tags: r, list, vector, permutation

i have this list of vector `out`:

```
[[1]]
[1] (1,5)(3)(4)(6)

[[2]]
[1] (3,6)(1)(4)(5)

[[3]]
[1] (3,4)(1)(5)(6)

[[4]]
[1] (3,5)(1)(4)(6)

[[5]]
[1] (4,6)(1)(3)(5)

[[5]]
[1] (4,5)(1)(3)(6)

[[6]]
[1] (5,6)(1)(3)(4)
```

take one elemente for example  `out[[5]]` `(4,6)(1)(3)(5)`, i would  generate all permutation of element with all possible order, for example:

```
{(4,6)(3)(1)(5)},{(3)(4,6)(5)(1)}...
```

Comment: Generally "combination" refers to selecting elements when order doesn't matter, and "permutation" refers to selecting elements when order does matter. So I think you want to generate all *permutations* of a particular list element.

Comment: And for that, I'd say [this is a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11095992/903061).

Comment: I'm guessing the next question will be how to split each element into its components ... and `lapply(l, function(a) Filter(nzchar, strsplit(a, "[()]")[[1]]))` is a sloppy start for that :-)

Comment: or `lapply(l, function(a) strsplit(gsub("\\(", "", a), ")"))`

Comment: I'm not sure what the elements of your data structure actually are - they sort of look like Cycle Notation for permutations: https://dlmf.nist.gov/26.13 .  Is that what they are?  Or are they elements in parentheses just opaque chunks you can shuffle around?  Or are the commas functioning as decimal points, like @aliendeg assumed?

Comment: @KenWilliams, I had the same thought. The output looks really similar to what the package `permutations` produces. For example `permutations::allperms(3)` produces `()    (23)  (12)  (123) (132) (13)`. It isn't exactly the same, but it's close.

Comment: 'library(partitions)                                                                                        
parts <- listParts(length(x))
out <- rapply(parts, function(ii) x[ii], how="replace")'                                                         my datastructure is generate from this code, what i would be do is generate all partitions from a set and fro each partitions compute all permutations

Comment: Also, it's interesting that you created that using the `partitions` library and I guessed that you used the `permutations` library. If you look closely at the documentation, `allperms` from `permutations` is simply a wrapper of a function from the `partitions` library.

Comment: @JosephWood, sorry if i don't write but is a vector

Comment: @JosephWood do you think that i can solve my problem in better way?

Comment: @antonionuzzo, yes for sure... I'm working on a solution right now that only uses the `partitions` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what the OP is looking for:

```
out <- list(c("(1,5)","(3)","(4)","(6)"), c("(3,6)","(1)","(4)","(5)"), 
            c("(3,4)","(1)","(5)","(6)"),c("(3,5)","(1)","(4)","(6)"), 
            c("(4,6)","(1)","(3)","(5)"), c("(4,5)","(1)","(3)","(6)"), 
            c("(5,6)","(1)","(3)","(4)"))

library(RcppAlgos)
myPerms <- lapply(out, function(x) {
    unlist(permuteGeneral(x, length(x), FUN = function(y) {
        paste0(c("{", y, "}"), collapse = "")
    }))
})
```

We use `permuteGeneral` from `RcppAlgos` (I am the author) as we can utilize the `FUN` argument to pass a custom function that will be applied to each permutation (i.e. `paste0(c("{", y, "}"), collapse = "")`).

Here is the output of the 5th element:

```
myPerms[[5]]
[1] "{(4,6)(1)(3)(5)}" "{(4,6)(1)(5)(3)}" "{(4,6)(3)(1)(5)}"
[4] "{(4,6)(3)(5)(1)}" "{(4,6)(5)(1)(3)}" "{(4,6)(5)(3)(1)}"
[7] "{(1)(4,6)(3)(5)}" "{(1)(4,6)(5)(3)}" "{(1)(3)(4,6)(5)}"
[10] "{(1)(3)(5)(4,6)}" "{(1)(5)(4,6)(3)}" "{(1)(5)(3)(4,6)}"
[13] "{(3)(4,6)(1)(5)}" "{(3)(4,6)(5)(1)}" "{(3)(1)(4,6)(5)}"
[16] "{(3)(1)(5)(4,6)}" "{(3)(5)(4,6)(1)}" "{(3)(5)(1)(4,6)}"
[19] "{(5)(4,6)(1)(3)}" "{(5)(4,6)(3)(1)}" "{(5)(1)(4,6)(3)}"
[22] "{(5)(1)(3)(4,6)}" "{(5)(3)(4,6)(1)}" "{(5)(3)(1)(4,6)}"
```

If you really want permutations with repetition, simply set `repetition = TRUE` in `permuteGeneral`. Of course, if you want a more useable output, we can drop the custom `FUN` altogether.

## UPDATE

After learning more about how the OP obtained `out` above, we can better attack the problem. First we find out that the OP uses `listParts` from the library `partitions`. Looking at the source code we have:

```
listParts
function (x) 
{
    f <- function(pp) {
        out <- split(seq_along(pp), pp)
        class(out) <- c(class(out), "equivalence")
        out
    }
    apply(setparts(x), 2, f)
}
<bytecode: 0x10d7b09f8>
<environment: namespace:partitions>
```

We can alter this to obtain all permutations:

```
permListParts <- function (x) 
{
    f <- function(pp) {
        out <- split(seq_along(pp), pp)
        myPerms <- perms(length(out))
        apply(myPerms, 2, function(x) {
            temp <- out[x]
            class(temp) <- c(class(temp), "equivalence")
            temp
        })
    }
    apply(setparts(x), 2, f)
}
```

We note that we are going against the intent of `listParts`... quoting the documentation:

> ***"Note that (12)(3)(4) is the same partition as, for example, (3)(4)(21) as the equivalence relation is the same."***

Oh well... here is the output for permutations of length 3:

```
permListParts(3)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] (1,2,3)


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] (1,3)(2)

[[2]][[2]]
[1] (2)(1,3)


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] (1,2)(3)

[[3]][[2]]
[1] (3)(1,2)


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
[1] (2,3)(1)

[[4]][[2]]
[1] (1)(2,3)


[[5]]
[[5]][[1]]
[1] (1)(2)(3)

[[5]][[2]]
[1] (1)(3)(2)

[[5]][[3]]
[1] (2)(1)(3)

[[5]][[4]]
[1] (2)(3)(1)

[[5]][[5]]
[1] (3)(1)(2)

[[5]][[6]]
[1] (3)(2)(1)
```

Comment: Hi, sorry, but with this  fuction  i had a problem of efficency, because with large vector don't compute all permutations and R crash. I would know if is possibile before compute partitions,  then for a  partitions of length  x                                 
 (for example [1] (3) (2) (1) length is 3)                                                          
 compute all permutation or  caclute permutations only for partitions of length x

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
test <- list(list(1,5),3,4,6)
combn(test,2)
> combn(test,2)
     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] List,2 List,2 List,2 3    3    4   
[2,] 3      4      6      4    6    6
```

This would give you all the possible combinations of 2 elements from your list. If you want to do that for each element of your main list you can then use a `for` or `lapply` on it.

try:

```
lapply(out, function(x) combn(x,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about gtools packages

```
out <- list(
 c(1.5,3,4,6),
 c(3.6,1,4,5),
 c(3.4,1,5,6),
 c(3.5,1,4,6),
 c(4.6,1,3,5),
 c(4.5,1,3,6),
 c(5.6,1,3,4))


require(gtools)

allPerm <- function(x){

  return(permutations(length(x), length(x), x))
}
```