# R order vectors so that difference between most of the elements are positive

Tags: r, sorting, vector, difference

I have two vectors

```
A = c(30709,28587,21672,20873,19877)
```

```
B = c(20213,21865,26217,30558,31674)
```

Vector B is always sorted in ascending order

I need to shuffle vector A in such a way that when taking difference (A-B), most of them should yield result +ve.

Here, output A needs to look like (20873,28587,30709,19877,21672) because this order will give me 3 differences(A-B) which will be +ve

Comment: do you have a threshold

Comment: I didn't get you threshold as if ?

Comment: but the difference also dependds on the order of 'B'

Comment: Here B is always sorted in ascending order

Comment: there could be more than one combinations that can rresult in this case `c(20873, 19877, 28587, 30709, 21679) - B` also gives 3 positive.  So, it is not clear which one you would pick

Comment: I posted a solution with `permutations`.  Please check if that helps

Comment: Can we do it without using any external package ?

Comment: It can be done but the `arrangements` is pretty fast and if we do with base, it would not be that efficient.  the function is written in C

Comment: See stackoverflow.com/questions/11095992/… or my edited post for base R functions.

Answer (score 2):

So many options for permutations... here is one using the `Rfast` package:

```r
library(Rfast)
#> Loading required package: Rcpp
#> Loading required package: RcppZiggurat
A = c(30709,28587,21672,20873,19877)
B = c(20213,21865,26217,30558,31674)
pa <- permutation(A)
pA <- sapply(seq_len(dim(pa)[1]), function(x) pa[x,] - B)
pa[colSums(sign(pA)) == max(colSums(sign(pA))), ]
#>        [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
#>  [1,] 20873 19877 28587 30709 21672
#>  [2,] 20873 21672 28587 30709 19877
#>  [3,] 20873 28587 19877 30709 21672
#>  [4,] 20873 28587 21672 30709 19877
#>  [5,] 20873 28587 30709 19877 21672
#>  [6,] 20873 28587 30709 21672 19877
#>  [7,] 20873 30709 28587 19877 21672
#>  [8,] 20873 30709 28587 21672 19877
#>  [9,] 21672 19877 28587 30709 20873
#> [10,] 21672 20873 28587 30709 19877
#> [11,] 21672 28587 19877 30709 20873
#> [12,] 21672 28587 20873 30709 19877
#> [13,] 21672 28587 30709 19877 20873
#> [14,] 21672 28587 30709 20873 19877
#> [15,] 21672 30709 28587 19877 20873
#> [16,] 21672 30709 28587 20873 19877
```

**Edit:**
base R version:

```r
A = c(30709,28587,21672,20873,19877)
B = c(20213,21865,26217,30558,31674)

permutation <- function(x) {
    if (length(x) == 1) {
        return(x)
    }
    else {
        res <- matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = length(x))
        for (i in seq_along(x)) {
            res <- rbind(res, cbind(x[i], Recall(x[-i])))
        }
        return(res)
    }
}

pa <- permutation(A)
pA <- sapply(seq_len(dim(pa)[1]), function(x) pa[x,] - B)
pa[colSums(sign(pA)) == max(colSums(sign(pA))), ]
#>        [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
#>  [1,] 21672 30709 28587 20873 19877
#>  [2,] 21672 30709 28587 19877 20873
#>  [3,] 21672 28587 30709 20873 19877
#>  [4,] 21672 28587 30709 19877 20873
#>  [5,] 21672 28587 20873 30709 19877
#>  [6,] 21672 28587 19877 30709 20873
#>  [7,] 21672 20873 28587 30709 19877
#>  [8,] 21672 19877 28587 30709 20873
#>  [9,] 20873 30709 28587 21672 19877
#> [10,] 20873 30709 28587 19877 21672
#> [11,] 20873 28587 30709 21672 19877
#> [12,] 20873 28587 30709 19877 21672
#> [13,] 20873 28587 21672 30709 19877
#> [14,] 20873 28587 19877 30709 21672
#> [15,] 20873 21672 28587 30709 19877
#> [16,] 20873 19877 28587 30709 21672
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

<sup>Reference: [Generating all distinct permutations of a list in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095992/generating-all-distinct-permutations-of-a-list-in-r)</sup>

Comment: Is there any way that it can be implemented without any packages ?

Comment: @Gaurav Chavan: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095992/generating-all-distinct-permutations-of-a-list-in-r for base R functions

Answer (score 1):

This solution could be computationally expensive if your vectors A and B have many elements, but in this case it's instantaneous.

```
# create a dataframe of all possible permutations of A
perms <- as.data.frame(gtools::permutations(length(A), length(A), A))
# add a column that will signal how many positive differences A-B there will be
perms$num_positives <- 0

# for each row in the dataframe, calculate how many positive differences A-B there are
for (i in 1:nrow(perms))
  perms$num_positives[i] <- sum(perms[i,] > B)

# order the dataframe according to the descending number of positive differences
perms[order(perms$num_positives, decreasing = TRUE), ]
```

Output

```
       V1    V2    V3    V4    V5 num_positives
28  20873 19877 28587 30709 21672             3
34  20873 21672 28587 30709 19877             3
38  20873 28587 19877 30709 21672             3
40  20873 28587 21672 30709 19877             3
41  20873 28587 30709 19877 21672             3
...
```

`num_positives` is the number of positive differences between A and B.

In your case there are many permutations of A that get a number of positive differences A-B equal to 3, as shown in the output.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `permutations` from `arrangements` to create all the permutation, then subtract it with 'B', get the `rowSums` of the difference greater than 0, and subset the 'm1' where the count is `max`, In this case, the `max` is 3 and these are the combinations that would create that `max` difference of positive values

```
library(arrangements)
m1 <- permutations(A, length(A)) 
c1 <-  rowSums(m1- B[col(m1)] > 0)
m1[c1 == max(c1),]
#     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
# [1,] 21672 30709 28587 20873 19877
# [2,] 21672 30709 28587 19877 20873
# [3,] 21672 28587 30709 20873 19877
# [4,] 21672 28587 30709 19877 20873
# [5,] 21672 28587 20873 30709 19877
# [6,] 21672 28587 19877 30709 20873
# [7,] 21672 20873 28587 30709 19877
# [8,] 21672 19877 28587 30709 20873
# [9,] 20873 30709 28587 21672 19877
#[10,] 20873 30709 28587 19877 21672
#[11,] 20873 28587 30709 21672 19877
#[12,] 20873 28587 30709 19877 21672   ####
#[13,] 20873 28587 21672 30709 19877
#[14,] 20873 28587 19877 30709 21672
#[15,] 20873 21672 28587 30709 19877
#[16,] 20873 19877 28587 30709 21672
```