# Count the number of occurring a specific ordered sequence in R

Tags: r

I have this vector

```
data<-c(3,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,3,3,3,1,3,1,1,3,2,1,3,3,3,3)
```

I need to find the number of times I can have 1, then 2, then 3 (in this particular order)

So the expected answer for the above vector is 98 times (all possible ways).

Is there any efficient way to do so, as my actual problem will be a vector with many unique values (not simply as 1,2,3).

and here is my codes that give me the answer

```
data<-c(3,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,3,3,3,1,3,1,1,3,2,1,3,3,3,3)
yind<-which(data==2)
y1<-yind[1]
y2<-yind[2]
sum(data[1:y1]<data[y1])*sum(data[y1:length(data)]>data[y1])+sum(data[1:y2]<data[y2])*sum(data[y2:length(data)]>data[y2])
```

but it is not suitable for a vector with many unique values.For example

```
set.seed(3)
data2 <- sample(1:5,100,replace = TRUE)
```

and then count how many times I can have 1, then 2, then 3, then 4, then 5 (all possible ways).

Thank you

Comment: How much more efficient than the solution you have already written?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095992/generating-all-distinct-permutations-of-a-list-in-r) might be of interest.

Comment: Could you please describe in more detail what you need? The way I see it there is only one way of getting 1, 2, 3 *in this particular order*.

Comment: @Jan if you work from left to right and you count all the possible ways you can obtain 1,2,3. As we have only two 2 here, it is easy to count as 6s one x 9s three + 11s ones x 4s three =98. But when you have more than 3 numbers it becomes difficult.

Comment: @Scott Hunter, by efficient means I can calculate it on my computer at least, for large numbers it is already a challenge.

Comment: Thanks @NelsonGon, but I cannot see how this link works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using non-equi joins from `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
v <- data2
tofind <- 1L:5L
dat <- data.table(rn=seq_along(v), v)

paths <- dat[v==tofind[1L]][, npaths := as.double(1)]
for (k in tofind[-1L]) {
    paths <- paths[dat[v==k], on=.(rn<rn), allow.cartesian=TRUE, nomatch=0L, 
        by=.EACHI, .(npaths=sum(npaths))]
}
paths[, sum(npaths)]
```

Output for your `data` is 98.
Output for your `data2` is 20873.

—-
Explanation:
Picture a n-nomial tree where each layer is the sequence of numbers that you are looking for and each vertex is the position of numbers in the data vector. For example, for data = c(1,2,1,2,3) the tree would look like

[image]

So the code goes through each layer and find the numbers of paths going into each vertex on that layer. The code uses a non-equi inner join to find those paths going into the vertices.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am still trying to understand the codes. When I increase the sample size to 1000, I got an error.

Comment: Yes. prob have to break it down somehow. I need simply the proportion, meaning need to divide this number over all possible combinations (so not in that specific order 1<2<...<k)

Comment: Thank you, it is super fast. But I am not sure if I am doing something wrong, when k=7 or above  (not 5 as above in your example) and for sample size 1000. I got this error below. Warning message:
In gsum(npaths) :
  The sum of an integer column for a group was more than type 'integer' can hold so the result has been coerced to 'numeric' automatically for convenience.

Comment: wah u are dealing with really large numbers. its integer overflow. let me update. 193478053782?

Comment: Wow, it seems to work, thank you very much. The next step for me is to understand the codes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TcM i refactor to use one `[`. should be faster and less memory intensive

Comment: Thank you very much @chinsoon12,  much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach with `expand.grid`.

```
FindComb <- function(vector,variables){
  grid <- do.call(expand.grid,lapply(variables,function(x) which(vector == x))) 
  sum(Reduce(`&`,lapply(seq(2,ncol(grid)), function(x) grid[,x-1] < grid[,x])))
}
FindComb(data,c(1,2,3))
#[1] 98
```

I expect it will not scale well with longer vectors or more numbers, but it works OK for smaller scales:

```
set.seed(3)
data2 <- sample(1:9,1000,replace = TRUE)
FindComb(data2,c(8,2,3))
[1] 220139
```

Comment: Yes, for 5 numbers I got an error. '''> set.seed(3)
> data2 <- sample(1:5,1000,replace = TRUE)
> FindComb(data2,c(1,2,3,4,5))
 Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)'''

Comment: It's possible to improve this approach by filtering the vectors before calling `expand.grid`. But since you can't tell us what your goal is, it's probably not worth the effort.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. My goal is simply to find this number "set.seed(3)
data2 <- sample(1:k,1000,replace = TRUE)
FindComb(data2,1:k)" but for large k, k=9 or 10 would work. And then repeat this process for many data sets (different vector than above but takes values from 1 to k). So your example above is perfect but instead for c(8,2,3) I would need 1:9. Thanks